# Shrinking a bulky GeoJSON

Tags: python, shapefile, geojson, geopandas

I converted shapefile to GeoJSON, the shapefile is 10mb and the result of GeoJSON was around 30. In order to make this conversion, I used the following code:

```
import geopandas as gpd

SHP_FILE = './00ent.shp'
JSON_FILE = './mexico.geojson'

geodf = gpd.read_file(SHP_FILE)
geodf = geodf.to_crs(epsg='4326')
geodf.to_file(JSON_FILE, driver="GeoJSON")
```

How can I shrink this file with GeoPandas or another Python library? I used an online tool, and I can reduce it to 2MB, but I need to do this programatically.

Any solution?

Comment: How did you shrink it?

Comment: https://mapshaper.org/ with this page

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`mapshaper`](https://github.com/mbloch/mapshaper/#installation) via command line. It's not a Python based tool but a JavaScript NodeJS based tool. You can call the `mapshaper` command line utility using [Python subprocess](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html)